# Websphere Liberty profile deployment Error

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

How to configure WebSphere liberty profile and data source configuration steps using Oracle DB and please tell me the step by step process.
I have installed liberty profile (WebSphere Liberty 17.0.0.4) after deployed the EAR file it's getting below error 
FYI...,
hitting the app url getting below error

> SRVE0095I: Servlet has become temporarily unavailable for service: /*****

I have verified the logs it shows the below error continuously

> Error log:-
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SystemSettingsService' defined in class path resource [config/core-spring-
>   context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'V3DataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'V3DataSource' defined in class path resource [config/datasource-spring-
>   context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type 
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource'; nested exception is 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)

Comment: This page has details on configuring Liberty with an Oracle data source: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html  However, I'm guessing there's something wrong in your Spring application or configuration based on the error.

Comment: i have configured DB  based the above link but still app is not up getting same error .

Comment: This looks like Spring misconfiguration. Double check your your datasource configuration as it looks it has issues.

Comment: Below is my data source config file and is it code related error or any liberty profile configuration issue. if it is configuration issue can you please provide the steps to resolve the issue.   <library id="oracle-lib">
<fileset dir="/u01/wlp/wlp/lib/was/Oracle/" includes="orai18n-12.1.0.2.0.jar ojdbc7.jar"/>
</library>
 <dataSource id="DefaultDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/basic_ds" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
<jdbcDriver libraryRef="oracle-lib"/>
 <properties.oracle url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DB_Hostname:1521/aDB_sid" user="Db_username" password="DB_Password" />
    </dataSource>